# What is the fastest way to open urls in new tabs via Selenium - Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to create a python script to open up a lot tabs

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver


driver =webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.msn.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.cnn.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.apple.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com');")

# driver.quit()
```

When I run I get

[image]

Is what I have right now is the fastest way?

---

I used to have this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver =webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

#1
driver.get("http://msn.com")

#2
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.get("http://cnn.com")

#3
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")

#4
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.get("https://www.apple.com")

#5
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

#6
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

It works but it is painfully `slow`.

---

I start with 6 now, but I want to load 100 tabs.

Also, how do I get rid of my first weird looking tab? 
I am even sure why it is there.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade the chromedriver(>2.25)/chrome browser(>55.0) on your MAC to remove the empty data; tab.
You can use `threading` or `multiprocessing` to speed up the process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver =webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("http://msn.com")
def func1():
  print 'launching: MSN'
 driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.msn.com');")

def func2():
  print 'launching: CNN'
  driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.cnn.com');")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=func2)
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()

def runInParallel(*fns):
  proc = []
  for fn in fns:
    p = Process(target=fn)
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)
  for p in proc:
    p.join()

runInParallel(func1, func2)
```

Depending on how many CPUs you have, the load of the machine, the timing of many things happening in the computer will have an influence on the time the threads/process start. Also, since the processes are started right after creation, the overhead of creating a process also has to be calculated in the time difference you see.

Answer (score 1):

So we already have have 2 approaches at out disposal to open **`New TAB`** with **`Selenium`**.

Your previous approach with **`send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')`** is bound to consume more time as we **`switch_to.window()`** and **`get("http://www.url.com")`** too. Hence slower.

Your current approach with **`execute_script`** is bound to be faster as we are simply injecting **`Java Scripts`** to open new **`TAB`** s with **`URL`** s.

Now, the reason you see a **`Blank Window`** is because once you initialized the browser through :

```
driver =webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

After this, we haven't invoked the **`get()`** method to open any **`URL`**. Rather we have straight taken help of **`JavascriptExecutor`** to open **`NEW TAB`** s. Hence the first **`TAB`** remains unused.

---

### Update :

To bring the `unused TAB` into the play, we can access the first of the `URL` s through the first `TAB` invoking `get()` method as follows :

```
driver =webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("http://www.msn.com")
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.cnn.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.apple.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com');")
```

---

### Summary :

To open a **`New Blank TAB`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")
```

To open a **`New TAB with url`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://facebook.com/');")
```

Comment: How can I get rid of unuse tab .?

Comment: Is my approach is the fatest way ?

Comment: Well, apparently it is faster. But when you will start working on the new `TAB` s through `Automation Scripts` you have to often sync up the fast moving `Driver` with the lagging `Browser Client`.