# Open several URL in several New Tab on same session in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I need to navigate to several urls (via Firefox). I want to open each url in a different tab (but not in a different window). I've read many similar questions on SO - the only suggestion that seems to work some of the time is:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", url);
```

However this does not work all the time - sometimes it opens the link in a new window instead of new tab.

I thought it might have to do with the specific Firefox configuration I'm using but changing value for `browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external` (to 3) does not seem to resolve the issue.

For extra clarity, I'm not talking about opening a link on a web page in new tab (I know this is discussed in other threads here on stackoverflow) I'm talking about directly navigating to several urls in new tab.

So how can I get Firefox to open urls in new tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to open urls in new tabs via Selenium - Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543795/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-open-urls-in-new-tabs-via-selenium-python/47545387#47545387)

Comment: @Amit Asaf i have added an answer for your solution. Please replace the code you tried with the anwser. Please let me know your feedback

Answer (score 2):

The exact java solution for openning new tab in current session is below

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('http://www.amazon.com');");
```

It will automatic switch to new tabs handle. If you want to switch between tabs driver handle please implement this.

```
String mainWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();

for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

**EDIT** : If you use url as a variable then use the below code

```
 String url = "http://www.amazon.com/";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('" + url + "');");
```