# Open a new website when a tab is clicked through Webdriver in Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, tabs, automation

I am trying to open a new browser tab through Webdriver in Selenium. However the new tab opened is blank. I am trying to send a website link to the Webdriver object however the link is still not opening.

Here is my code:

```
   // Assuming path is already set
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseURL = "https://www.flipkart.com/";
    driver.get(baseURL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);

    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    Iterator itr = handles.iterator();
    String parent_window = (String) itr.next();
    System.out.println(parent_window + "....." + driver.getTitle());

    String child_window = (String) itr.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(child_window);
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.flipkart.com/");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to open urls in new tabs via Selenium - Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543795/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-open-urls-in-new-tabs-via-selenium-python)

Comment: Well that code was given for Python language, I asked for code in java

Comment: `Java` or `Python` the implementation through `JS` is always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //switches to new tab
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0)); // switch back to main screen        
    driver.get("https://www.news.google.com");
```