# How to force a link that is invoked via javascript to open in a new tab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a webpage that opens up hyperlinks via javascript as shown below. I am using Selenium with Python.

```
<a href="javascript:openlink('120000020846')">
<subtitle>Blah blah blah</subtitle>
</a>
```

Using XPATH, I was able to open up the hyperlink using the following Python code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
xpath = '//a/subtitle[contains(text(),"Blah blah blah")]'
link_to_open = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath);
link_to_open.click()
```

However, the link opens in the same tab.  This is not what I want, as I want the links to open in a new tab, so that I can retain the information of the current page and continue processing the rest of the links.

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can give me some pointers if this can be done?

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to open urls in new tabs via Selenium - Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543795/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-open-urls-in-new-tabs-via-selenium-python)

Comment: Hi my question is different from the so-called 'duplicate' ones. My links are javascript already. By default, even if a human clicks on a javascript link, he cannot open it in a new tab. I want to know if there is any workaround for this? 

I already know how to open links in a new tab with normal hyperlinks (ie. Those without javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can force a link to open in a new tab through the [**ActionChains**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) implementation as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

action = ActionChains(driver)
link_to_open = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a/subtitle[contains(.,'Blah blah blah')]")
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link_to_open).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, thks so much for your comments. I tried your code and it still opens in the same tab.  The page I am trying to scrape is this one. [link](https://www.skillsconnect.gov.sg/sop/WebPageHandler?pn=WP_TMCourseSearch&p=L3E&action=advance)   You can try entering a keyword like 'data' inside the first textbox and click the 'Search' button. A new page will then open and the first link that is visible is "Data Interpretation & Analysis"

I am trying to open up this link in a new tab.  Using the code you gave, it still opens up the link in the same tab :(   Any idea why? thank you! :)

Comment: @DoraChua I am afraid, the `<a>` tag of your interest is having the `href` attribute as **javascript:setActionAndSubmitAction('120000020846')** so neither you can open the link in a new TAB _Manually_ or through _Automation_.