# how to open a new empty tab in firefox using selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

But it doesn't add any new tab.

Also tried this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open();");
```

But it opens a new window instead of using the same one.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543795/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-open-urls-in-new-tabs-via-selenium-python/47545387#47545387) helps you?

Comment: @DebanjanB no, it does not, changing the script to `window.open('','_blank');` is still openning a new window... and the discussion is Python, not Java.

Comment: A new window or tab is basically the same thing... it's just whether it's docked or not. There's probably some setting that you can change to have new windows be a new tab vs a new window that you can set yourself.

Comment: @JeffC how can I do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use the `Robot` class.

```
try{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
} catch(Exception e) { }
```